# How to print "<h1>Heading</h1>" in html

Tags: html, html-heading

the problem is i want to output `"<h1>heading</h1>"` without skipping the heading tags....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <title>first page</title>
       </head>
          <body>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
         </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What exactly you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want

`&lt;h1&gt;Heading&lt;/h1&gt;`

This will print:

<h1>Heading</h1>

Comment: can u plz discribe this coz im new to html

Comment: If you want to render a character `<` into your HTML document, you print `&lt;` instead. Correspondingly, to display `>` print `&gt;`.

Comment: I mean, just paste `&lt;h1&gt;Heading&lt;/h1&gt;` instead of `<h1>Heading</h1>` in your HTML file.

Comment: thankx @Ishamael
but is &lt; and &gt; works on all characters or only on <>

Comment: Then I didn't understand your problem right. I thought you wanted to display `<h1>` instead of actually creating a header. `&lt;` and `&gt;` is the way to display characters `<` and `>` in HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72731/discussion-between-sharan-sondhi-and-ishamael).

Answer (score 0):

in php, you can do this `print htmlspecialchars('<your tags/>')` failure to which, you need to know the character code of the tag.